# Disable Windows 7 auto shutdown even if it overheats

Tags: windows-7, bios

I need to disable all auto-shutdown features and/or functions with Windows 7, even for detected overheating problems, by any application, script, code or the Windows 7 operating system.

I'm looking for a way to stop any auto-shutdown operations too if any occur, but ensuring ALL are disabled would be best.

Comment: Why, is this your way of seeking revenge on some one else's computer? The question reads as if there is malicious intent here (but no offence is meant if it's not)... Why would you want to do this?

Comment: You won't be able to do this.  The best you can do is raise the trigger levels for the built-in protection provided the BIOS exposes them.

Comment: It is a bad idea, overheating for a long time dries out thermal grease causing the system to overheat more and more

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is almost certainly impossible and it is most certainly a very very bad idea. When the temperature rises above a certain point, the various components of the computer stop working. When it reaches past that point, they can be permanently damaged, essentially they melt. In order to avoid this, modern hardware will automatically shut itself down when it is approaching the dangerous temperatures. This is hard coded into the hardware itself, it has nothing to do with the Operating System (Windows or Linux or OSX or whatever).

While it *might* conceivably be possible to hack into your BIOS and disable this (I doubt that it is, but I cannot say for sure) it is such a bad idea and so dangerous to do so that it seriously would be cheaper, faster and easier to just throw your computer out of the window. In fact, unless you live in a high floor, that might even cause it less damage than letting it run at extreme temperatures.

Answer (score 0):

Your CPU has hard-wired overheating protection. Intels had it 12 years ago (see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NxNUK3U73SI)) and I hope modern AMDs have it too. So even if you've found a way to disable motherboard's overheating protection, CPU would probably freeze. Of course it's not very useful when frozen, so auto shutdown sounds like a good option.

If you want to see a PC on fire, there are simplier ways to achieve that. But don't try it at home ;)

Answer (score 0):

you know you could do a simple process. just start to play a game, when you know it its overheating (making noise) you could run the vacuum cleaner or compressed air in the vents do it until some temperature drops. just a tip place the laptop where some air can pass in and out easily.

Comment: OP didn't specify the type of computer and is wishing to circumvent all features of a computer that prevent hardware damage. While providing input that offers an alternative path is good in some cases, it's not in many others. This is a low quality workaround. A permanent solution would be better.

Answer (score -1):

Go to

Control Panel - Power Options - Change plan settings - Change advanced power settings - Processor power management - System cooling policy

change this from active to passive and apply

Comment: This is not an accurate answer for the question. This setting only affects fan/clock speed behavior. It will not affect the settings that are firmware on the BIOS to shutdown the PC at a certain temperature.